# adjust items in bootstrap5 navbar using normal css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

guys I am making a navbar using bootstrap-5 and I want to adjust colors for some items like navbar and, tags, navbar background, and burger menu colors I tried first with tags but it is not working I will show you the code for both HTML and CSS.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap');
html {
  font-size: 90%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-padding: 9rem;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  max-width: 1650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

html body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(24, 129, 210, 0.7);
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style1.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./images/titleiconw.png" sizes="32*32" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <title>Corporate Solutions</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span>C</span> Solutions</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">about us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">why choose us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">careers</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">our clients</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">contact us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <button class="btn">request a quote</button>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

i want to change a tags color,navbar background color,burger menu color and navbrand color can anyone help me, please.
thank you so much

Comment: Do you mean like the "a" style in your CSS is not affecting your a tags?

Comment: yes no effect at all for color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Added Font awesome because easy to change hamburger icon color:***

```
 <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
 />
```

***Added new class to nav and remove the old ones:***

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg custom-nav">
```

***Add new hamburger icon instead of navbar-toggler-icon***

```
<span>
  <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
</span>
```

***Add new css:***

```
.custom-nav {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.custom-nav ul a {
  color: rgb(19, 106, 213);
}

.hamburger {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: rgb(19, 106, 213);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with "!important"

```
a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: rgba(24, 129, 210, 0.7) !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
}
```

or you can try placing your css under the bootstrap

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style1.css" />
```